# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 2

Tags: selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

i have tried to login to a Website via selenium (Im new at this) and i get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 2
```

My geckodriver.log

```
1528902746472   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1528902746524   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:55108
1528902748429   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.ZWTWUTIgFCiP"
/usr/bin/firefox: 1: /usr/bin/firefox: ELF¸l40ó4: not found
/usr/bin/firefox: 4: /usr/bin/firefox: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

My Python Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)
driver.get("https://www.exampledomain.com")



username = driver.find_element_by_id("txtUser")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("txtPass")

username.send_keys("XXXXX")
password.send_keys("XXXXX")

driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
driver.close()
```

Sorry, but I have searched the last 2h in the Web to solve the Problem, and now i am really confused :/

I have tried to Install Firefox (for my 32bit linux machine, but it doesn't solve the issue)
Maybe I have done something wrong

Comment: at what point are you getting error

Comment: [...]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities